# ¿Es correcto "Eso fue una de las razones por (la/las) que te ayudé"?

Tags: sintaxis, concordancia-gramatical

No estoy seguro de cuál de los dos es correcto:

- Eso fue una de las razones por la que te ayudé
- Eso fue una de las razones por las que te ayudé

Al principio, creí que la forma correcta era "por la que", ya que sólo hablamos de "UNA" de las razones. Pero, cuando pongo "That was one of the reasons why I helped you" en Google Translate o Bing Translator, ambos me dan "Eso fue una de las razones por LAS que" te ayudé.

Además, después de haberlo reconsiderado, me parece que "por LAS que" es la forma correcta. De cualquier manera, me gustaría confirmarlo aquí y también buscar una explicación para conseguir un mejor entendimiento de la gramática española.

Comment: Si te entra la duda demasiado, siempre puedes decir simplemente *las razones por que te ayudé* :-)

Comment: Uy @guifa a mi no me suena bien. Creo que se debe ser consistente con el plural o el singular. "Es es LA razón por LA que te ayudé" o "Esa es una de LAS razones por LAS que te ayudé"

Comment: @DGaleano concuerdo contigo en cuándo usar *la* o *las*, pero son prescindibles estos artículos cuando vienen después de una preposición corta (a/de/en/por/para/con). P.ej.: «es uno de los materiales con (los/Ø) que suelo trabajar». No obstante, la elisión es menos frecuente con *por* probable debido a la existencia de la conjunción *porque* (nunca dije que sonaría la mar de bien o normal, solo que era válida ;-) )

Comment: @guifa de acuerdo. No dije que estuviera mal gramaticalmente, solo que no me suena bien. Gracias por la información adicional.

Answer (score 12):

Creo que se debe ser consistente con el plural o el singular.

Si usas el singular: "Es LA razón por LA que te ayudé" = *Solo te estoy ayudando por una única razón*

> ¿Me ayudaste por que soy tu cuñado?. Si, esa es **la** razón por **la** que te ayudé, (y nada más).

Si usas el plural: "Es una de LAS razones por LAS que te ayudé". En este caso *hubo varias razones que me llevaron a ayudarte* y nos estamos refiriendo a una de ellas.

> ¿Me ayudaste por que soy tu cuñado?. Si, esa es una de **las** razones por **las** que te ayudé, y la otra es porque soy tu amigo.

Answer (score 3):

La forma correcta es la plural *las*.

Piénsalo así: si alguien ayudó a alguien y ahora está hablando de *una de las razones* de haberlo ayudado, esto significa que hubo más de una razón. La proposición independiente sería

> *Te ayudé por (varias / ciertas  / muchas) razones.*

La frase compuesta debería ser:

> *Ésa fue una de las razones por las que te ayudé.*

En esta frase, *por las que te ayudé* es una proposición subordinada. Por definición las subordinadas modifican algún otro componente de la oración. La oración completa tiene dos constituyentes unidas por una cópula, y la segunda constituyente tiene a su vez varias "anidadas" dentro:

`[Ésa] fue [una [de las razones [por las que te ayudé]]].`

Está claro que el complemento indirecto (instrumental) en *por las que te ayudé* debe ser el plural *las*, ya que refiere a *las razones*. La forma en que se ordena esta clase de proposición, en español, no permite otra cosa.

Puedes comprobar que la subordinada modifica a *razones* simplemente quitándola o reemplazándola por otra cosa:

- `[Ésa] fue [una [de las razones [que tuve para ayudarte]]].`
- `[Ésa] fue [una [de las razones [de mi ayuda]]].`
- `[Ésa] fue [una [de las razones [principales]]].`
- `[Ésa] fue [una [de las razones]].`

Answer (score 2):

Justo antes de poner este mensaje, logré probarme a mi mismo que "las" era el pronombre correcto. Hice esto traduciéndolo a inglés (mi lengua materna), después de lo cual repetí el mismo proceso en español. A mi juicio, lo siguiente no debería dejar ningún lugar a dudas.

- **English first:**

That was one of the reasons why I helped you.  -->

There were several reasons why I helped you. That was one of THEM.

THEM = The reasonS why I helped you.

- **Español:**

Eso fue una de las razones por la/las que te ayudé. -->

Había varias razones por **LAS** que te ayudé. Eso fue *una de ellas*

Eso fue una de....(una de qué????)....(una de)..... **LAS** (*varias*) razones por **LAS** que te ayudé.

**Otro ejemplo:**

Había varias razones por (la/las) que te ayudé, una de **las cuales** es que eres mi amigo.

Claro que debemos usar una de LAS cuales y no una de LA cual....Eso no tendría ningún sentido.

**Un ejemplo más:**

Mike es uno de los chicos con quien/quienes he luchado.

Hay varios chicos **CON QUIENES** he luchado. Mike es uno de **ELLOS**.

Mike es uno de los chicos con **QUIENES** he luchado.